# What is the AngularJS equivalent approach to the Razor syntax's helper

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently migrating to use AngularJS instead, but I do have a helpful helper in the Razor syntax.

```
@helper DataField(MvcHtmlString fieldName)
{
     <input id="@fieldName" name="fieldName" />
     @Html.DropDownList(fieldName + "_UnitOfMeasure", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

Then I have many data fields on my form so I just use this:

```
@DataField(Html.NameFor(m => m.Electricity_Original))
```

My Model is now going to be pulled into AngularJS using $http to get the data as JSON, so this old way won't work any more.  The basic aim here is to be able to change the layout and things in one place rather than have to update hundreds of them.

I am still learning Angular, but I am getting tied up around whether to use [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It feels like there should be something simple.

Comment: I'd have thought a custom directive would do the trick.

Comment: yeah you'll need to do a directive